# ASP.NET MVC Razor Footer Contact Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have been searching all over the internet and can't find a solution for this.  I am fairly new to MVC.  How can I create a "Contact Us" form in a footer that is rendered as a partial and displayed on every page?  I am just trying to get the form to send an email to us with the client's information.

Answer (score 1):

You should create `_Layout.cshtml` and use it for your pages.

See [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: I am trying to put a form on the _Layout.cshtml and that is the problem.  The site has 5 different controllers and I need the form to be able to submit no matter what page the site is on.  The Form is in the _Layout.cshtml which is displayed on every page of the site.

Comment: You can define form as `<form id="loginForm" action="@Url.Action("SignUp", "Login")" method="post"> </form>` and use a separated Controller to process form submit